# Who are the Baby-looking villains attacking universe 6?

Tags: dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

In episode 7 of the Dragon Ball Heroes anime, Baby-looking villains

[image]

> attack Hit, Cabba, Kale and Caulifla

Who are they? are they from the same race of Baby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are *Oren* and *Kamin* and are main antagonists of the *"Universal Conflict Saga"*. The characters have been referred to as twin artificial life forms ([Source](https://twitter.com/Cipher_db/status/1080162633297215488)). They share the appeareance of a Neo Machine Mutant Tuffle([Source](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Machine_Mutant))([Source](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Tuffle)).